# Accidentally lost all files

Tags: permissions, login, files

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  I am new to Ubuntu.  I recently swapped over from Windows 10 after my OS became virtually unusable and exceptionally slow.

I was tinkering one day and suddenly found myself unable to access my files at all.

I rebooted and tried to log back in but couldn't.  Whenever I clicked on my username and entered my password it would just kick me back out to the user select screen.

Following an online tutorial, I solved the login issue with the following command:

```
sudo chown myusername:myusername -R /home/myusername
```

This solved the login problem, but I found that all my files were missing. My programs were still installed, but all of my browser extensions and files have disappeared.

I would be grateful if someone could explain what I did so that I can avoid doing it in future and help me get my files back if possible.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if you had space problems in $HOME (/home/$USER/ or your user directory) as machine can become slow when out of disk space. You rebooted (did you do it cleanly? via menu or Sysrq keys?) then unable to login..  A GUI (graphical user interface) login requires space in $HOME and it'll abort if insufficient space is available (a TUI or text login isn't impacted so you normally check there, ie. ctrl+alt+f4 to switch to text terminal & login..)  I don't know what `chmod` command you executed sorry, thus can't evaluate it's effect.. but I'd check space, do you use encryption?

Comment: hmmm... Do you know the reason your Windows install started failing?   It sounds to me like your hard drive might be failing.  If you can remember, the most important info you could give would be what you did when you were "tinkering".  If this caused the problem, it would sure help to know what it was.  Can you look in the `/home` directory to see if there is maybe another user with your files?

Comment: @Nmath I think my previous windows installation was failing because it had a great deal of bloatware installed when I got it (Dell Support Assist, etc.), eventually I got sick of it and decided to swap to Ubuntu for configurability. Alas, I cannot remember what I was doing exactly when I was "tinkering" I don't know how or if I can get the terminal logs up from then to see. I think I was trying to sort out a DRM issue with Firefox and 4OD. I've also checked the home directory and there is only one user, which is the one I'm currently using.

Comment: @guiverc I have over 900gb of disk space free so I don't think it's that. No I don't use encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Every app setting (as browser extensions, bookmarks etc) is inside "/home/yourusername" folder. So you can press ctrl+h inside your-home-folder to notice if there are hidden folders with strange attributes that you can fix.

If there are no files anywhere, you can try a free app for linux is called [r-linux](https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/). With r-linux you could search your disk (if it is working fine) and you should be able to find any of your missing files.

Although you should read the very useful comments above. Hope it helps